# Android 12 - Override default splash screen logo using splash screen api setSplashScreenTheme fails

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, android-12, android-splashscreen

I trying to override the default splash logo using SplashScreen API, setSplashScreenTheme. But it fails to set overridden logo but takes the default application logo. Is there way to override default logo programatically.

Setting theme directly via manifest overrides logo, but wanted set this programatically.

Also I am not able to override style "Theme.SplashScreen", even when target and compile sdk is set to 31. Only able to override if android Splashscreen library is integrated

Answer (score 2):

setSplashScreenTheme works if it is called from onResume.